# How to make use Bootstrap Grid with PHP

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-grid

Basically I want to make this page responsive so it is easily viewed on a mobile device using only the bootstrap grid(container, rows, columns) no styling from Bootstrap. Right now it is not doing so despite me having tried numerous ways. My other pages that do not have PHP have not given me much trouble but this one has and I cannot get it to display well on a phone.

I tried starting with the container at the very top of the page, outside the php block then making a row for my h2 tags and trying to do the same inside my while loop. However, it did not become responsive and the results and the column headers were not align properly.

"headerprofile.php"

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css"/>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

```
<?php
require_once('includes/headerprofile.php');
require_once('includes/database.php');
?>

<html>
     <head>

        <style>
form.searchbar {
                 margin: 25px 50px;
            }

h1.profile {
margin: 25px 50px;
}
    h2 {     
  margin: 20px 45px;
     }
 h1 {     
   text-align: center;
     } 

p {
  margin: 20px 45px;
}

.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

body {margin: 0;}

ul.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(119,13,41);
}


ul.nav li {float: left;}

ul.nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.nav li a:hover:not(.active) {

    background-color: rgb(237,235,235);
    color: rgb(119,13,41);
    }

ul.nav li a.active {
        background-color: rgb(169,5,51);
    }

ul.nav li.right 
        {
        float: right;
    }

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  ul.nav li.right, 
  ul.nav li {float: none;}
}

.table  { 
                display: table;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                text-align: left;
            }
            .tr{ 
                display: table-row; 
                padding: 7px;
            }
            .td{ 
                display: table-cell;
                padding: 7px;
            }


</style>
    </head>
<body> 
<h1 class="profile"> My Appointments </h1>

        <div class ="search" id="browse">
            <p> Find your appointment below or search by keyword</p>

        <form id="" class="searchbar" action="searchAppt.php" method="get">
           <input type="text" name="terms" size="40" class = "sbar" required value="Search by keyword" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');"
                       onblur="if (this.value == '') {
                                    this.value = 'Enter keyword';
                                }"
                       onfocus="if (this.value == 'Enter keyword') {
             this.value = '';
         }"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <button type="submit" class = "btn">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <h2> Future Appointments</h2>
    <p>
    <label> Appointment(s): <br/> 

        <?php     
            $sql = "select a.id, a.lname, a.fname, a.phonenum, a.room, a.building, a.issue, a.start_time, a.end_time, a.username 
            from appointments as a
            where a.email = '". $_SESSION['email'] ."' and a.start_time >= NOW()
            ";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                echo "<div class='table'>
                <div class='tr'>
                <div class='td'><b>Ticket #</b></div>
                <div class='td'><b>Username</b></div>
                <div class='td'><b>Building</b></div>
                <div class='td'><b>Issue</b></div>
                <div class='td'><b>Date</b></div>
                <div class='td'><b>Start Time</b></div>
                <div class='td'><b>End Time</b></div>
                <div class='td'></div>
                </div>";
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $starttimefuture = strtotime($row["start_time"]); //converts date time received from MySQL into a string
                    $endtimefuture = strtotime($row["end_time"]);
                    $datefuture = date("m/d/y", $starttimefuture);
                    $startfuture = date("g:i A", $starttimefuture);
                    $endfuture = date("g:i A", $endtimefuture);
                    $buildingfuture = str_replace('_',' ', $row["building"]);
                    echo "<div class='tr'>
                    <div class='td'>".$row["id"]."</div>
                    <div class='td'>".$row["username"]."</div>
                    <div class='td'>".$buildingfuture."</div>
                    <div class='td'>".$row["issue"]."</div>
                    <div class='td'>".$datefuture."</div>
                    <div class='td'>".$startfuture."</div>
                    <div class='td'>".$endfuture."</div>
                    <div class='td'><form action='ticketdetails.php' method='post'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row["id"]."'>
                        <input type='submit' value='Ticket Details'></form>
                    </div>
                    </div>";
                }
                echo "</div>";
            } else {
                echo "<br/><b>No future appointments!</b>";
            }
        ?>
    </label>
    </p> 

    <hr>
```

Comment: Is this embedded inside some other page? If not, you still need to add the core of the page (the `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` tags) to have this parsed correctly.

Comment: @TiesonT. I just left that part out to save space, this is all included inside the body tag of my page. [link](https://imgur.com/ykcM2sq) it looks like this on desktop, need this to scale for mobile.

Comment: You're not really saving much space by leaving those out. Missing meta tags tends to be the most common reason that Bootstrap's responsive styles don't kick in, so at the very least, edit your question to include whatever meta tags you're using. It's also invalid to embed div tags inside a label, especially when that label is embedded inside a paragraph tag.

Comment: @TiesonT. gotcha, I edited it and added all of it

Comment: What does headerprofile.php contain? You need the doctype and meta tags shown in the starter template (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template) for the media queries to kick in, which is how Bootstrap's responsive design works.

Comment: I apologize, but there is what I have. @TiesonT.

Comment: Okay, that's the majority of the problem, then - those tags from headerprofile.php need to be inside the head tag.

Comment: @TiesonT. they are in header tag, still not resizing page.

Comment: There is a `<header>` tag, which is not the same as the `<head>` tag, so probably want to be careful which word you use. Just FYI.

Comment: I want it to display like this when responsive. I'm not sure why when it's on large screen it is not stretching the width of the page but I want it to respond as such. [Code Pen](https://codepen.io/miller765/pen/YMzPKJ) @TiesonT.

Comment: Your example is doing some things that conflict with Bootstrap's grid system, which would require more space than comments are intended to provide. That being said, the content you're displaying is tabular - is there a reason to not just use a table? That's kind of what they're for. If you want to discuss this, I'd suggest creating a chat room (https://chat.stackoverflow.com/ - if you want to but can't create a room, let me know).

Comment: @TiesonT. I am unable to, new user. However, I would greatly appreciate that and yes after looking at w3 and things I believe displaying it all in a table is the way to go.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190968/chat-for-how-to-make-use-bootstrap-grid-with-php

Comment: @TiesonT. unable to chat due to not having a high enough reputation

Comment: @TiesonT. just created my account

Answer (score 0):

assuming a bootstrap4 grid, and only example - this would be 3 columns wrapping on a mobile

```
<h2> Future Appointments</h2>
    <p>
    <label> Appointment(s): <br/> 
    </label>

<div class="container">
        <?php     
            $sql = "select a.id, a.lname, a.fname, a.phonenum, a.room, a.building, a.issue, a.start_time, a.end_time, a.username 
            from appointments as a
            where a.email = '". $_SESSION['email'] ."' and a.start_time >= NOW()
            ";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                echo "
            <div class='row'>
               <div class='col-4 col-md-1'><b>Ticket #</b></div>
               <div class='col-4 col-md-2'><b>Username</b></div>
               <div class='col-4 col-md-2'><b>Building</b></div>
               <div class='col-4 col-md-2'><b>Issue</b></div>
               <div class='col-4 col-md-2'><b>Date</b></div>
               <div class='col-4 col-md-1'><b>Start Time</b></div>
               <div class='col-4 col-md-1'><b>End Time</b></div>
               <div class='col-4 col-md-1'></div>
            </div>";
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $starttimefuture = strtotime($row["start_time"]); //converts date time received from MySQL into a string
                    $endtimefuture = strtotime($row["end_time"]);
                    $datefuture = date("m/d/y", $starttimefuture);
                    $startfuture = date("g:i A", $starttimefuture);
                    $endfuture = date("g:i A", $endtimefuture);
                    $buildingfuture = str_replace('_',' ', $row["building"]);
                    echo "<div class='row'>
            <div class='col-4 col-md-1'>".$row["id"]."</div>
            <div class='col-4 col-md-2'>".$row["username"]."</div>
            <div class='col-4 col-md-2'>".$buildingfuture."</div>
            <div class='col-4 col-md-2'>".$row["issue"]."</div>
            <div class='col-4 col-md-2'>".$datefuture."</div>
            <div class='col-4 col-md-1'>".$startfuture."</div>
            <div class='col-4 col-md-1'>".$endfuture."</div>
            <div class='col-4 col-md-1'>
                <form action='ticketdetails.php' method='post'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row["id"]."'>
                    <input type='submit' value='Ticket Details'>
                </form>
            </div>
                    </div>";
                }
            } else {
                echo "<br/><b>No future appointments!</b>";
            }
        ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very helpful and might have just solved my problem. I was not really sure how I needed to wrap it but this lets me see it well. Definitely going to try this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Given what you've shown, you need to move at least the headerprofile.php include so that it renders inside the `<head>` tag:

```
<?php
require_once('includes/database.php');
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
     <head>
        <?php require_once('includes/headerprofile.php'); ?>

        <style>
            form.searchbar {
                margin: 25px 50px;
            }

            h1.profile {
            margin: 25px 50px;
            }
            h2 {     
              margin: 20px 45px;
            }
            h1 {     
               text-align: center;
            } 

            p {
              margin: 20px 45px;
            }

            .responsive {
              width: 100%;
              height: auto;
            }

            body {margin: 0;}

            ul.nav {
              list-style-type: none;
              margin: 0;
              padding: 0;
              overflow: hidden;
              background-color: rgb(119,13,41);
            }


            ul.nav li {float: left;}

            ul.nav li a {
              display: block;
              color: white;
              text-align: center;
              padding: 14px 16px;
              text-decoration: none;
            }

            ul.nav li a:hover:not(.active) {
                background-color: rgb(237,235,235);
                color: rgb(119,13,41);
            }

            ul.nav li a.active {
                background-color: rgb(169,5,51);
            }

            ul.nav li.right {
                float: right;
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
              ul.nav li.right, 
              ul.nav li {float: none;}
            }

            .table  { 
                display: table;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                text-align: left;
            }
            .tr{ 
                display: table-row; 
                padding: 7px;
            }
            .td{ 
                display: table-cell;
                padding: 7px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <h1 class="profile"> My Appointments </h1>

        <div class ="search" id="browse">
            <p> Find your appointment below or search by keyword</p>

            <form id="" class="searchbar" action="searchAppt.php" method="get">
               <input type="text" name="terms" size="40" class = "sbar" required value="Search by keyword" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');"
                           onblur="if (this.value == '') {
                                        this.value = 'Enter keyword';
                                    }"
                           onfocus="if (this.value == 'Enter keyword') {
                 this.value = '';
             }"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <button type="submit" class = "btn">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <hr>

        <h2> Future Appointments</h2>

        <p>
            <label> Appointment(s):</label>     
        </p> 

        <?php     
            $sql = "select a.id, a.lname, a.fname, a.phonenum, a.room, a.building, a.issue, a.start_time, a.end_time, a.username 
            from appointments as a
            where a.email = '". $_SESSION['email'] ."' and a.start_time >= NOW()
            ";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                echo "<div class='table'>
                <div class='tr'>
                <div class='td'><b>Ticket #</b></div>
                <div class='td'><b>Username</b></div>
                <div class='td'><b>Building</b></div>
                <div class='td'><b>Issue</b></div>
                <div class='td'><b>Date</b></div>
                <div class='td'><b>Start Time</b></div>
                <div class='td'><b>End Time</b></div>
                <div class='td'></div>
                </div>";
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $starttimefuture = strtotime($row["start_time"]); //converts date time received from MySQL into a string
                    $endtimefuture = strtotime($row["end_time"]);
                    $datefuture = date("m/d/y", $starttimefuture);
                    $startfuture = date("g:i A", $starttimefuture);
                    $endfuture = date("g:i A", $endtimefuture);
                    $buildingfuture = str_replace('_',' ', $row["building"]);
                    echo "<div class='tr'>
                    <div class='td'>".$row["id"]."</div>
                    <div class='td'>".$row["username"]."</div>
                    <div class='td'>".$buildingfuture."</div>
                    <div class='td'>".$row["issue"]."</div>
                    <div class='td'>".$datefuture."</div>
                    <div class='td'>".$startfuture."</div>
                    <div class='td'>".$endfuture."</div>
                    <div class='td'><form action='ticketdetails.php' method='post'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row["id"]."'>
                        <input type='submit' value='Ticket Details'></form>
                    </div>
                    </div>";
                }
                echo "</div>";
            } else {
                echo "<p><b>No future appointments!</b></p>";
            }
        ?>

        <hr>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've also cleaned up some of the markup that would be invalid (divs inside labels, etc.).